# Magento changing block titles

Tags: magento

[image]

I want to change the titles of the Tabs in the Accordian at the bottom. I no longer want "Additional Info" I want "Product specs"

I also want to change where it says "Related" and have it say "Add A Garage Stop"

Magento 1.9.3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tabs on product page are defined in layout xml

*/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml*

```
            <block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml">
                <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Additional Information</value></action>
            </block>
```

Related products are defined in template
*app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list/related.phtml*

```
<div class="block block-related">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Related Products') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
```

if you use custom theme replace `base/default` with your theme path. If files do not exist in custom theme, you can safely copy them over with same paths

**UPDATE**

You can use local.xml file of your theme to change tab title

/app/design/frontend/**(YOUR THEME PATH)**/layout/local.xml

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
         <remove name="product.attributes"/>
         <block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml">
                <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
        <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Product specs</value></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

(will only work if your Theme behaves like default magento theme)

Comment: I was able to change the related products Title.

However the 'Addition Info' I am using a theme, It did not have a catalog.xml file, so i copied the one from base into the theme layout folder, and had to add the action setTitle.

The only thing I am thinking with this, is that I created attributes for these products, and that is what is showing up under this tab. So maybe there is a file for additional attributes that needs to be edited.

Comment: I seem to still be unable to change this tab.

www.popstops.com

Comment: your template does not look like magento default. Tabs are wrapped in list elements. In this case you can only search through whole codebase for string "Additional Info" and see where it leads you. Most likely you will find some custom template in your theme.

Comment: also take a look into 

app/design/frontend/**[Theme]**/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

and subtemplates under app/design/frontend/**[Theme]**/template/catalog/product/view/